# Downloading font failed during Winetricks installation of Steam

Tags: ubuntu, installation, wine, steam, winetricks

I was using Winetricks to install the Valve Steam client on my Ubuntu machine.

However, the download failed for a font. I don't see a way to tell it to start over – what do I do now?

Comment: Can you post the actual output of winetricks?

Comment: it wasnt that the Wintricks install failed, but the font executables that it downloads didnt... well.. execute.  Arial.exe (or whatever its called) just hung.  I dont know how to make it download the arial font, or if needs more than that...